# How to change the target android operating system in Cocos2D-x 2.x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x-2.x

I noticed it is always building for API level 8, or android 2.2.
How can i change the Android the project is built for?

Answer (score 1):

You could change AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
```

Change the minSdkVersion to whatever api level.

The minSdkVersion would determine the minimal requirement for the Android.

Comment: Thanks dude. Although I have a feeling it'll be overwritten if I try to build the project again. Still it would work temporarily at the least.

Comment: I think this setting wouldn't be override when rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a question about Android develop, you should take this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) as a reference.

> android:minSdkVersion
>
> An integer designating the minimum API Level required for the application to run. The Android system will prevent the user from installing the application if the system's API Level is lower than the value specified in this attribute. You should always declare this attribute.